# mongoose .save() ignores ObjectId _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema collection **A**. Then, I create a new object as follows

```
var myA = new A({
    name: 'A simple name'
});
```

As long as I know, once we have done this, a new **_id** attribute is created for that object. This means that at the end of the day, **myA** should look (and it actually looks) like

```
{
    name: 'A simple name',
    _id: ObjectId
}
```

the problem is that when I hit

```
myA.save()
```

it is saved into mongodb with a different **_id** than the previously created.

An idea on why this could be happening? I'm using mongoose 4.4.8

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you create a new document with `new A({...` it internally marks itself as new document which is evaluated later when calling `save()` to generate an appropriate MongoDB statement - and this 'flag' is probably not updated immediately when calling `save()`. This has the positive side effect of having the possibility to quickly create clones of documents when you want to generate test data :)

If you want to update your newly saved document right after creation then you should do that in the callback of the [save](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) method which gets the saved document in its 2nd parameter.